# Range of $\alpha$ If tangents are drawn from external point to the Hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

> Two tangents can be drawn to the different branches of the hyperbola $$\frac{x^2}{1}-\frac{y^2}{4}=1$$ from the point $(\alpha,\alpha^2)$. Then Range of $\alpha$ is

$\bf{My\; Try::}$If Line $y=mx+c$ is tangent to the hyperbola, Then we get equation of

tangent in slope form as $$y=mx\pm \sqrt{a^2m^2-b^2}$$

so here we get $$y=mx\pm \sqrt{m^2-4}$$

Now tangents line passess through $(\alpha,\alpha^2).$

So we get $$\alpha^2=m\alpha\pm \sqrt{m^2-4}$$

So $$(\alpha^2-m\alpha)^2=m^2-4\Rightarrow \alpha^4+m^2\alpha^2-2m\alpha^3=m^2-4$$

So $$\alpha^4-2m\alpha^3+m^2\alpha^2-m^2+4=0$$

Now how can i solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$(\alpha^2-1)m^2-2\alpha^3m+\alpha^2+4=((\alpha-1)m-(\alpha^2-2\alpha+2))((\alpha+1)m-(\alpha^2+2\alpha+2))$$

- If $\alpha\notin\{-1,1\}$ then your equation has two solutions in $m$,
  These two solutions are distinct if and only if $\alpha\notin\{-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\}$, and this gives the desired two tangents to the hyperbola. While if $\alpha\in\{-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\}$ then $(\alpha,\alpha^2)$ is on the hyperbola
  and there is just one tangent through that point.
- If $\alpha\in\{-1,1\}$ then the equation gives the slop of one tangent, but there is also another *vertical* tangent through that point to the hyperbola.

We conlude that the desired range of alpha is  $\alpha\notin\{-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\}$.

Comment: How  $(\alpha,\alpha^2)$   is on the hyperbola?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, it is a mistake, thank you, it is now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of tangent at $P(\sec t,2\tan t)$ is $$x\sec t-\dfrac y4\cdot2\tan t=1\iff2x-y\sin t=2\cos t$$

If this has to be pass through  $(\alpha,\alpha^2),$

$$2\alpha-\alpha^2\sin t=2\cos t$$

$$\implies\alpha=\tan\dfrac t2+1,\cot\dfrac t2-1$$

So, $\alpha$ can assume any real value.